# WordPress Categories not showing in sidebar (post-new.php)

Tags: php, wordpress

When adding or editing a post, categories are not showing in the sidebar - the area is here but the list is empty.

In the console (JS), I have these errors :

> (WARNING) [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #_wpnonce:​ ​
>
> (ERROR) post-new.php:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>   in JSON at position 2
>
> (WARNING) DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:
>   chrome-extension://eakacpaijcpapndcfffdgphdiccmpknp/scripts/content_page.map
>
> (WARNING) DevTools failed to parse SourceMap:
>   https://[my-domain]/wp-includes/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css.map

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQnt7.png)

It's only happening in live - **I have the exact same version on a local WAMP server, everything is working great - Same database, same theme.** (exported with All In One WP Migration).

I've done tests, **it appears that with the classic editor plugin, the bug is gone** - But I would like to keep the Gutenberg editor, and I would like to understand what's happening too.

It happens only on posts, not custom post types, where I don't have errors in the console neither.

The live server is running PHP 7.3.

I use very few plugins. (YoastSEO, ACF PRO, Wordfence, Imagify, All in One WP Migration, W3 Total cache). All the plugins are also on my local server, where the bug is not occuring.

Anyone can give me a hint ?

Thanks !

EDIT :

Here's a screen of my problem

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2bF0.png)

Comment: First, there are two elements on your document with the same ID, but this is not the core issue. Just a thing you need to fix.
Please paste your `post-new.php` here so we can help.

Comment: As i think if you are using block editor. Then you may added some actions on `pre_get_posts` and it is the problem of that.

Comment: Share a site url or screen so, we can easy to get idea.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. I've shared a screenshot of the dashboard and the empty list (in the original post). @AliQorbani : I use pre_get_posts yes, but it used to work before ! I use this hook to orderby my custom post type table (in the dashboard).

Comment: @AmitRahav the two elements that has the same ID are generated by Wordpress itself, it's a security system. (wordpress nonce) that prevents malicious admin actions using admin links. The problem may be coming from here, but, why and where ? I think this is hardcoded in Wordpress core. So why would I have a problem now ? Remember : it works perfectly on locale environment !

Comment: you can disable gutenberg block editor by installing `classic editor` plugin or you have to change your hook to return correctly json response everytime.

Comment: @AliQorbani I would like to keep the Gutenberg editor, I don't know when but I must have added something to cause it. It was working fine before. Thanks for your input anyway, you're right there's not bug if I activate the classic editor. :)